# Adding the FeLogin in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, bootstrap-modal

Good day Everyone

I'm trying to add the FeLogin Form in a Modal window i created. Till now i managed to create a Modal window in the Main.html. Then i tried to implement the variable which i linked 30_Page.ts and created in LoginBox.ts.
Then again it doesn't seem to take effect.

Till now my outcome is only an empty Modal window which pops open and is able to be closed.

But the form it self doesn't get generated.

Does anyone know what the issue is when i try to implement the form into my modal?

*Edited:*

Ive noticed that the issue lies in `lib.LoginBox < plugin.tx_felogin_pi1`.
Since when look at it in the TypoScript Object Browser. The Variable isn't full like the others.

I also tried to change it to `lib.LoginBox = USER` or `lib.LoginBox = USER_INT` and `lib.LoginBox = COA` or `lib.LoginBox = COA_INT`.

The outcome only gave me a `<!--INT_SCRIPT Error`.

*{Extension}/Resources/Private/Templates/Main.html*

```
...
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Anmelden</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {LoginBox}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*{Extensions}/Configuration/Lib/Include/LoginBox.ts*

```
/* LoginBox.ts */
lib.LoginBox.2 < plugin.tx_felogin_pi1
lib.LoginBox.2 {

    storagePid = 19
    showForgotPasswordLink = 1

    welcomeHeader_stdWrap >
    welcomeMessage_stdWrap >
    logoutHeader_stdWrap >
    logoutHeader_stdWrap >
    successHeader_stdWrap >

    showLogoutFormAfterLogin = 0
    noSuccessMessageAfterLogin = 1
    dateFormat = d.m.Y H:i

    redirectMode = login
    redirectPageLogin = 56

    _CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >

    _LOCAL_LANG.de {
       ll_welcome_header =
       ll_logout_header = 
       username = Benutzername
       password = Passwort
    }
}
```

*{Extensions}/Configuration/Page/Setuo/30_Page.ts*

```
# Template Einbinden
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE 
page.10 {   
    partialRootPath = typo3conf/ext/cf_base_efco/Resources/Private/Partials/
    layoutRootPath = typo3conf/ext/cf_base_efco/Resources/Private/Layouts/

    # template file
    file = typo3conf/ext/cf_base_efco/Resources/Private/Templates/Main.html
    file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
    file.stdWrap.cObject {
        key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
        key.override.field = backend_layout

        default = TEXT
        default.value = {$plugin.tx_cf_base_efco.fluid.templates}Main.html

        1 = TEXT
        1.value = {$plugin.tx_cf_base_efco.fluid.templates}Main.html

        2 = TEXT
        2.value = {$plugin.tx_cf_base_efco.fluid.templates}Home.html
    }

    # libs einfuegen
    variables {
        HeaderLogo < lib.HeaderLogo
        MainNavigation < lib.MainNavigation
        LoginBox < lib.LoginBox     
        SubNavigation < lib.SubNavigation
        Content1 < lib.Content1
        Content2 < lib.Content2
        Content3 < lib.Content3
        Seitentitel < lib.Seitentitel
        SeitentitelPlain < lib.SeitentitelPlain
        FooterNavigation < lib.FooterNavigation
        Copyright < lib.Copyright
        Breadcrumb < lib.Breadcrumb
        LangNavigation < lib.LangNavigation
        PageLink < lib.PageLink
        Slider < lib.Slider
        SearchBox < lib.SearchBox
        motto = TEXT
        motto.value = {$text.motto}
        copyright = TEXT
        copyright.value = {$text.copyright}
        legal = TEXT
        legal.value = {$text.legal}
        productGroup = TEXT
        productGroup.value = {$text.productGroup}
        shoppingBasket = TEXT
        shoppingBasket.value = {$text.shoppingBasket}

        efcoImagePath = TEXT
        efcoImagePath.value = {$plugin.tx_cf_base_efco.filepaths.images}
    }
}
```

I'm happy for any type of Feedback given.

Thank you for now.

Comment: Please add a question to your question. Is there any problem / error, it is hard to look into what is blocking you, or what is missing, and so on.

Comment: Ive added some more Detail into it if thats what you ment.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but what I see, that is the naming: you makes for your LoginBox an object: lib.LoginBox.2 but you uses a reference of lib.LoginBox. Check in the TypoScript Object Browser if the variable gets its correct value and try to change it to the same name as the main object. so lib.LoginBox.2

Comment: So i checked and i didn't find anything in the TypoScript Object Browser. I removed the .2 in my code and tried again and went to see if in the Object Browser anything could be seen. Yet it hasn't shown up.

Comment: Could you insert the login form as <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginBox" />

Comment: Ive tried to implement it. Then again it still displays the Modal empty and when i go look over the TypoScript Object Browser. The variable is still Empty.

Comment: The problem is maybe, that your LoginBox.ts is not included in the setup part. It explains why don't you see the lib.LoginBox inside the Object Browser

Comment: Thats odd because i have it included in the code LoginBox < lib.LoginBox. I also tried it with LoginBox < plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 which didn't work aswell.

Comment: This morning when i tried out the Login Form i was working fully. I feel like this post helped -> <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginBox" /> – Andrei Todorut